# Repetition in the table elements

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

Here I have the code for Firebase storage.

[image]

While doing this I am getting repetition in the table data. Here is my javascript code. I have done something logic mistake in the for loop.

```js
function gotMuch(dude, guy)
{
    var ex9 = dude.val();
    var sa9 = Object.keys(ex9);
    var s9 = sa9.length;
    console.log("Hello there" + s9 + "");

    var did = ex9.did;
    var dmark = ex9.dmark;
    var dname = ex9.dname;
    console.log(did);
    console.log(dmark);
    console.log(dname);

    var y = document.querySelectorAll(".subtable" + guy + "").length;
    console.log("Class length is" + y + "");

    var ytabl = document.querySelectorAll(".subtable" + guy + "");
    var yd1 = document.createElement("td");
    var yd2 = document.createElement("td");
    var yd3 = document.createElement("td");
    var space = document.createElement("br");
   
    for(var b = 0; b < y; b++)
    {
        var row = ytabl[b].insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    
        cell1.innerHTML = did;
        cell2.innerHTML = dname;
        cell3.innerHTML = dmark;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Move the `.innerHTML` *outside* the loop.

Comment: Hints: Use reasonable names for variables and functions. It is hard for an outsider to understand your code. Who is dude and who is guy? Did you notice that you execute the same selector twice?